# How to get Jasmine tests syntax highlighting in PhpStorm?

Tags: jasmine, phpstorm, karma-jasmine

I've just started using `PhpStorm (version 10)` and I'm now trying to set up some Karma and Jasmine tests on my project.

These tests work as expected but I fail to get rid of errors stating

> 'Unresolved function or method describe()'.
>    Same goes for 'it', 'expect' etc.

Seem like PhpStorm doesn't recognize the syntax at all.

What I've done so far is I've installed (with npm) the needed libraries, Karma, Jasmine, Karma-jasmine etc. I've also went to `setting->Languages & frameworks->Javascript` and tried adding some libraries to my project. I've downloaded and included the ones I'm using: Jasmine, Karma-Jasmine, Karma but the errors remain.

I then added a new library `(Libraries->Add...)` and included the directories from node_modules (which I've otherwise excluded from my project files) and sure enough I got rid of the errors but only after including a library called 'hoek'. I don't even know where that came from (dependency of something I've installed) but it seems to take care of the errors, unlike jasmine, jasmine-core etc. more likely ones.

Why is this and what could I do to more easily tell PhpStorm to use Jasmine syntax with my test files?

Answer (score 1):

To get Jasmine functions resolved, I'd suggest installing Jasmine typescript stubs (`Settings/Languages & Frameworks/JavaScript/Libraries`, Download..., choose '`jasmine`' from stubs dropdown). I'd also suggest removing other libraries you have configured (Jasmine, Karma-Jasmine, Karma)  from `JavaScript/Libraries` to avoid possible conflicts (of course, you still need to have them installed via npm to make your code work)